# Is it possible to use REST as a protocol via TCP-Sockets?

Tags: c#, rest, tcp, client-server, tcpsocket

I know that REST is using HTTP and HTTP is based on TCP.

My question is if it possible to use TCP sockets to connect between a client and a server (TCP handshake etc.) and then using REST as a "protocol" to handle the communication between the client and the server over the existing TCP connection?

*Please note that i have already read [Can I use TCP in a RESTful service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038316/can-i-use-tcp-in-a-restful-service)  and this question is not a duplicate of it. Thank you.*

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038316/can-i-use-tcp-in-a-restful-service

Comment: Thanks, but i already saw this. The question there is about using REST via the TCP protocol for its communications, and surely it does because HTTP is TCP based.

Iam asking if you can use REST as a protocol viaTCP-sockets.

Comment: What does "use REST as a protocol via TCP sockets mean"  Can you provide an example?

Comment: Unfortunatly not, because im asking if its possible somehow.

Comment: @Foon

I'd say something like you connect via TCP-client and server socket. After the connection is established you'd use HTTP and REST as the protocol for interactions between server and client

Comment: Sorry, still not understanding you.  What you described is what happens any time something uses REST (ignoring SSL and a host of other details): browser opens a client TCP socket to the web server and then sends HTTP messages over this socket.  If you do telnet www.server.com 80 and then type GET / and hit enter twice, you should get back an HTTP response

Comment: @Foon What i mean is that you do not close the TCP socket to the server, as long as the transaction isnt done. But i think i got your point, doing what I have in mind would be reinventing the wheel and also violating the concept of REST, right?

Comment: So, that's an interesting question (can I do multiple REST transactions over a single TCP socket), which I think is yes if you control the client end and are careful with HTTP keepalive headers, but there might be gotchas for the non-idempotent messages), but if the point is to cut out the HTTP layer, in my mind (and this was discussed in the suggested duplicate's answers), REST implies HTTP; you could certainly send GET /resource without the rest of the HTTP headers and have your server send the resource without HTTP response headers, but you lose the big benefit of building on a standard)

Comment: @Foon I reckon your suggestion for the question text is more what I have in mind. (The first one, I dont want to cut out HTTP)